# Find & rename variable in workspace, if either names exist

Tags: matlab

How could I search for a variable name in Workspace from a list of possible names & then rename the existing variable and use its data.

Example:

```
A_apple_tree = [2;2;1;4];
AppleTree = [2;2;1;4];
Apple_tree_a5 = [2;2;1;4];
```

are the same variable with different names. 
I'd like to scan through Workspace variables until it finds one, then rename it to, say:

```
Apple_Tree = [2;2;1;4];
```

The below code displays variables with partial string search, however the found variables names are contained in a cell array. Using `cell2mat` will convert the cell containing the variable name into char with no values.

```
namesWorkspace = who;
outStr = regexpi(namesWorkspace, 'apple');
ind = ~cellfun('isempty',outStr);
vars = namesWorkspace(ind);
Apple_Tree = cell2mat(vars);

Apple_Tree = 'apple_tree_a5' %%%..... instead of values for apple_tree_a5;
```

How could I call the existing variable with its data for later purposes?

Thank you,

Comment: This is typically indicative of poor choice of datatypes. The *name* of a variable should never be used to indicate much of anything. There are better data structures to store this information: `arrays`, [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html) for key/value pairs, etc.) Please reconsider your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume all given variables contain the **same data**, so you can just use the data of the first occurence. Simply assign it by [**`evalin`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html) in the base workspace:

```
Apple_Tree = evalin('base',vars{1})
```

To consider the case, that there is no matching variable name, I'd include a [**`try/catch`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) statement and throw an error. A more generic solution would be to combine `evalin` with [**`assignin`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html), so you can define a single string, e.g. `'apple'` and create a variable called `apple` containing the data of any apple-esk variable.

```
fruit = 'orange';
namesWorkspace = who;
vars = namesWorkspace(~cellfun('isempty',regexpi(namesWorkspace, fruit)));
try
    assignin('base',fruit,evalin('base',vars{1}))
catch
    error('No matching variable name!')
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.